# A couple of difficulties in Tauber theory lecture notes of prof. Yum-Tong Siu

Tags: proof-explanation, tauberian-theory

Reading trough the [lecture notes on Tauber theory](https://web.archive.org/web/20161020160706/http://www.math.harvard.edu/~siu/math212b/tauberian_theorem.pdf) of prof. Yum-Tong Siu I am a bit off right at the beginning. If someone could clarify the follow two steps in his proofs of Tauber's original 1897 theorem and the theorem of Hardy-Littlewood of 1914:

On p. 4 : We have assumed $n \geq N_0$ to be large enough so that the Tauber condition says $|na_n| < \epsilon$ (for arbitrary $\epsilon > 0$). How does it follow in the establishing of the second $\epsilon$-bound (for $|\sum_{n=0}^{N}a_n(1-x^n)|$) that

$$ \sum_{n=0}^{N}|na_n|(1-x) < N\epsilon(1-x)$$?

On  p. 5 : The very last line, why is $k+1 = \int_{t=0}^{1} t^k dt$? He continues using this throughout the remaining of the argument, so I guess it is not a typo. I am rather confused and a bit ashamed that I apparently do not understand calculus.

Both of these things seem flatly incorrect to me. But I am a noob and this document appears to have been written by an established professor (presumable, because his name is on it and I found it originally on his Harvard webpage). So I guess these ought to be typos but I do not see how to recover from them easily. Any thoughts?

Comment: I'd mention proving the prime number theorem using a [general Tauberian theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Tauberian_theorems) is harder, so take a look at [other proofs](http://www.dms.umontreal.ca/~koukoulo/documents/notes/primes.pdf) specialized for $\frac{\zeta'(s)}{\zeta(s)}$

Comment: @reuns Thank-you for the comment. I know of other proofs, although most  of them do have an implicit Tauberian theorem incorporated. At least since Newman's and Korevaar's work. The most prominent exception is obviously the elementary proofs of Erdos and Selberg and I guess the original work of Hadamardand de la Vallee Poussin.

Comment: Anyhow, I am not interested per se in a PNT proof. I want to get these lecture notes.

Comment: See p.69 of the link for the traditional proof. The main ingredient is analytic continuation and a bound for $\frac{\zeta'(s)}{\zeta(s)}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The estimate on p. 4 does not depend on the properties of $N_0$, only on the Tauberian condition $n|a_n|\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$.

Let $b_n=n|a_n|$. Then $b_n\to 0$, and hence the averages ${1\over N}(b_1+\cdots+b_N)$ will $\to 0$ as well. So if $N$ is large enough, ${1\over N}(b_1+\cdots+b_N)<\epsilon$, or $\sum_{k=0}^Nn|a_n|<N\epsilon$.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, yes. Somehow I got in my head that $N_0$ depended on $x$ because $N$ does and is related to $N_0$. I'd like to up-vote, but need five more points. So if you haven't you can up-vote my question then I have enough "reputation" apparently.

Answer (score 1):

- Write 
  $$\sum_{n=0}^N \,\lvert n a_n \rvert= \sum_{n=0}^{N_0-1} \,\lvert n a_n \rvert + \sum_{n=N_0}^N \,\lvert n a_n \rvert.$$

The first sum is a constant $C$, and the second sum can be controlled with the Tauber condition, so we get

$$
\sum_{n=0}^N \,\lvert n a_n \rvert \leq C+N\epsilon.
$$

Note that this bound is a little weaker than what you're asking for. We can still conclude the argument on page 4 by using this weaker bound : we have

$$
\left\lvert \sum_{n=0}^N a_n(1-x^n)\right\rvert \leq (C+N\epsilon)(1-x)\leq C(1-x)+\epsilon.
$$

Recall that $C$ is a constant that only depends on $\epsilon$ : there exists $\delta'>0$ such that when $x>1-\delta'$, $C(1-x)<\epsilon$. Now when $x>\max(1-\delta,1-\delta')$, one has

$$\left\lvert \sum_{n=N+1}^\infty a_nx^n\right\rvert \leq \epsilon
$$

and

$$
\left\lvert \sum_{n=0}^N a_n(1-x^n)\right\rvert \leq 2\epsilon.
$$

- We have $\int_0^1 t^k \,\mathrm{d}t=[t^{k+1}/(k+1)]_0^1=1/(k+1)$. The argument on p.5 is still correct : from

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty s_n(1-x^{k+1})x^n(x^n)^k \to A,
$$

multiplying both sides by $1/(k+1)$ yields

$$\frac{1-x^{k+1}}{(k+1)(1-x)}(1-x)\sum_{n=0}^\infty s_nx^n(x^n)^k \to A\int_0^1 t^k \,\mathrm{d}t.
$$

which is what is needed.

Comment: Thank-you for your help but this does not answer the question as posed. You give different bounds and have therefore not resolved the issue of the lecture notes. Also I know the last sentence you say, but then why is it different in the notes... is it a typo? If it is then how to rescue the argument. Etc.

Comment: Yes, because the bound, as stated in your original post, is false. Indeed, take $na_n=\epsilon$ for all $n\geq N_0$. We then have $\sum_{n=0}^N \,\lvert na_n \rvert = \sum_{n=0}^{N_0-1} \,\lvert na_n \rvert +(N-N_0+1)\epsilon = C-(N_0-1)\epsilon+N\epsilon$. But one could make $C$ as big as one wishes, so your bound does not hold.

Comment: @tristan But this example violates the Tauberian condition $a_n = o(1/n)$.

Comment: @PerManne Yes. Although one could easily build a counterexample with $a_n=o(1/n)$, my point was to show that the bound does not hold when we are only given the hypothesis $n\geq N_0 \implies \lvert na_n \rvert \leq \epsilon$.

Comment: @Ibrahim : i have edited both parts of my answers : the mistakes in the original text can easily be worked around. I hope you are now convinced.